# My Quill editor Bold Not work?

Tags: materialize, quill

Other tool working except the bold, When I click bold my text still not get bold? I work on materialize. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

I fixed the issue with css, the css must be placed after the materializecss

```
 .ql-editor strong{
     font-weight:bold;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed an ::ng-deep   (or /deep/ )  in front of my style to get it working:

```
    ::ng-deep .ql-editor strong{    
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.
Use `strong { font-weight: bold !important; }` in styles.scss and it will solve the problem.